# Sum and Difference of two SQL query result

Tags: sql

```
(SELECT ID_OF, Col, BNT,    
        SUM(size1) As size1, 
        SUM(size2) As size2,
        SUM(size3) as size3,
        SUM(size4) as size4,
        SUM(size5) as size5,
        SUM(size6)as size6,
        SUM(size7) as size7,
        SUM(size8) as size8,
        SUM(size9) as size9,
        SUM(size10) as size10,
        SUM(Total) as Total,ref 

FROM tblTailleOFALL 
GROUP BY ID_OF, Col, BNT, ref) 

(SELECT ID_OF, Col, BNT,    
        SUM(size1) As size1, 
        SUM(size2) As size2,
        SUM(size3) as size3,
        SUM(size4) as size4,
        SUM(size5) as size5,
        SUM(size6)as size6,
        SUM(size7) as size7,
        SUM(size8) as size8,
        SUM(size9) as size9,
        SUM(size10) as size10,
        SUM(Total) as Total,ref 

FROM tblTailleALL 
GROUP BY ID_OF, Col, BNT, ref)
```

I did this query in SQL Server and get this result

```
   Id_OF   Col   BNT   size1   size2   size3   size4   size5   size6   size7   size8   size9   size10   Total   ref
---------
    37623  738   A       60      60      60     30      30      0       0        0        0     0        240      131380
```

And This :

```
   Id_OF   Col   BNT   size1   size2   size3   size4   size5   size6   size7   size8   size9   size10   Total   ref
---------
    37623  738   A       60      60      60     30      28      0       0        0        0     0        238     131380
```

How can I subtract these two result in my query! I should get this as result

```
   Id_OF   Col   BNT   size1   size2   size3   size4   size5   size6   size7   size8   size9   size10   Total   ref
---------
    37623  738   A       0      0        0       0       2       0       0        0        0       0         2     131380
```

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks really familiar... 
But how about this?

```
 SELECT a.ID_OF, a.Col, a.BNT,    
    SUM(a.size1) - SUM(b.size1) As size1, 
    SUM(a.size2) - SUM(b.size2) As size2,
    SUM(a.size3) - SUM(b.size3) As size3,
    SUM(a.size4) - SUM(b.size4) As size4,
    SUM(a.size5) - SUM(b.size5) As size5,
    SUM(a.size6) - SUM(b.size6) As size6,
    SUM(a.size7) - SUM(b.size7) As size7,
    SUM(a.size8) - SUM(b.size8) As size8,
    SUM(a.size9) - SUM(b.size9) As size9,
    SUM(a.size10) - SUM(b.size10) As size10,
    SUM(a.total) - SUM(b.total) As total,
    a.ref
    FROM tblTailleOFALL a 
    JOIN  tblTailleALL b
      ON a.ID_OF = b.ID_OF
     AND a.Col = b.Col
     AND a.BNT = b.BNT
GROUP BY a.ID_OF, a.Col, a.BNT, a.ref
```

Answer (score 1):

A number of methods exist, depending on your actual logic, but for your given question, I'd say simply JOIN them together using either common table expressions, subqueries or temporary tables and then subtract the size column from the corresponding size column.

Something like this:

```
;WITH T1 AS 
(
    SELECT ID_OF, Col, BNT,    
        SUM(size1) As size1, 
        SUM(size2) As size2,
        SUM(size3) as size3,
        SUM(size4) as size4,
        SUM(size5) as size5,
        SUM(size6)as size6,
        SUM(size7) as size7,
        SUM(size8) as size8,
        SUM(size9) as size9,
        SUM(size10) as size10,
        SUM(Total) as Total,ref 

FROM tblTailleOFALL 
GROUP BY ID_OF, Col, BNT, ref) , 
T2 AS 
(SELECT ID_OF, Col, BNT,    
        SUM(size1) As size1, 
        SUM(size2) As size2,
        SUM(size3) as size3,
        SUM(size4) as size4,
        SUM(size5) as size5,
        SUM(size6)as size6,
        SUM(size7) as size7,
        SUM(size8) as size8,
        SUM(size9) as size9,
        SUM(size10) as size10,
        SUM(Total) as Total,ref 

FROM tblTailleALL 
GROUP BY ID_OF, Col, BNT, ref)
SELECT 
T1.size1 - t2.size1
 .....
 .....
 .....
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID_OF = T2.ID_OF
```

Use an outer join if they do not match 1 to 1 between the two queries
(example just to illustrate)

But as said - multiple ways exists of doing this.

You could also make a single query - I suspect - and subtract in that as well before SUM and GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

you can join the tables and subtract the values:

```
SELECT coalesce(a.ID_OF ,b.id) as id
     , coalesce(a.Col, b.Col)  as Col
     , coalesce(a.BNT, b.BNT)  as BNT
     , SUM(a.size1 -b.size1 )  As size1
     , SUM(a.size2 -b.size2 )  As size2
     , SUM(a.size3 -b.size3 )  as size3
     , SUM(a.size4 -b.size4 )  as size4
     , SUM(a.size5 -b.size5 )  as size5
     , SUM(a.size6 -b.size6 )  as size6
     , SUM(a.size7 -b.size7 )  as size7
     , SUM(a.size8 -b.size8 )  as size8
     , SUM(a.size9 -b.size9 )  as size9
     , SUM(a.size10-b.size10)  as size10
     , SUM(a.Total -b.Total )  as Total
     , coalesce (a.ref, b.ref) as ref
FROM tblTailleOFALL a
full outer join
     tblTailleALL b
on (    a.id = b.id
    and a.Col = b.Col
    and a.BNT = b.BNT
    and a.ref = b.ref)
group by 
       coalesce(a.ID_OF ,b.id)
     , coalesce(a.Col, b.Col)
     , coalesce(a.BNT, b.BNT)
     , coalesce (a.ref, b.ref)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just JOIN those two queries by ID_OF and subtract each column in an outer query:

```
SELECT a.ID_OF,
  a.Col,
  a.BNT,
  a.size1 - b.size1 AS size1,
  a.size2 - b.size2 AS size2,
  a.size3 - b.size3 AS size3,
  a.size4 - b.size4 AS size4,
  a.size5 - b.size5 AS size5,
  a.size6 - b.size6 AS size6,
  a.size7 - b.size7 AS size7,
  a.size8 - b.size8 AS size8,
  a.size9 - b.size9 AS size9,
  a.size19 - b.size10 AS size10,
  a.total - b.total AS total,
  a.ref
FROM (
  SELECT ID_OF,
    Col,
    BNT,
    SUM(size1) AS size1,
    SUM(size2) AS size2,
    SUM(size3) AS size3,
    SUM(size4) AS size4,
    SUM(size5) AS size5,
    SUM(size6) AS size6,
    SUM(size7) AS size7,
    SUM(size8) AS size8,
    SUM(size9) AS size9,
    SUM(size10) AS size10,
    SUM(Total) AS Total,
    ref
  FROM tblTailleOFALL
  GROUP BY ID_OF,
    Col,
    BNT,
    ref
  ) a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ID_OF,
    Col,
    BNT,
    SUM(size1) AS size1,
    SUM(size2) AS size2,
    SUM(size3) AS size3,
    SUM(size4) AS size4,
    SUM(size5) AS size5,
    SUM(size6) AS size6,
    SUM(size7) AS size7,
    SUM(size8) AS size8,
    SUM(size9) AS size9,
    SUM(size10) AS size10,
    SUM(Total) AS Total,
    ref
  FROM tblTailleALL
  GROUP BY ID_OF,
    Col,
    BNT,
    ref
  ) b ON a.ID_OF = b.ID_OF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT a.ID_OF, a.Col, a.BNT, 
      a.size1 - b.size1 as size1, 
      a.size2 - b.size2 as size2,
a.size3 - b.size3 as size3,
a.size4 - b.size4 as size4,
a.size5 - b.size5 as size5,
a.size6 - b.size6 as size6,
a.size7 - b.size7 as size7,
a.size8 - b.size8 as size8,
a.size9 - b.size9 as size9,
a.size10 - b.size10 as size10,
a.Total - b.Total as Total,
a.ref

    (SELECT ID_OF, Col, BNT,    
            SUM(size1) As size1, 
            SUM(size2) As size2,
            SUM(size3) as size3,
            SUM(size4) as size4,
            SUM(size5) as size5,
            SUM(size6)as size6,
            SUM(size7) as size7,
            SUM(size8) as size8,
            SUM(size9) as size9,
            SUM(size10) as size10,
            SUM(Total) as Total,ref 

    FROM tblTailleOFALL 
    GROUP BY ID_OF, Col, BNT, ref) AS a
    inner join 
    (SELECT ID_OF, Col, BNT,    
            SUM(size1) As size1, 
            SUM(size2) As size2,
            SUM(size3) as size3,
            SUM(size4) as size4,
            SUM(size5) as size5,
            SUM(size6) as size6,
            SUM(size7) as size7,
            SUM(size8) as size8,
            SUM(size9) as size9,
            SUM(size10) as size10,
            SUM(Total) as Total,ref 

    FROM tblTailleALL 
    GROUP BY ID_OF, Col, BNT, ref) AS b on a.ID_OF = b.ID_OF
```